# Give values from one column to another column in pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, '-', '-', 8, 9],
                   'C': ['-', 'b', 'c', '-', 'e']})
```

How can I replace the values in `df['B']` using corresponding values in `df['C']`, if `df['B']='-'` and `df['C']!= '-'`.

Expected output:

```
({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  'B': [5, 'b', 'c', 8, 9],
  'C': ['-', 'b', 'c', '-', 'e']})
```

[Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROlcw.png)

I used:

```
replace = (df['B'] == '-') & (df['C'] != '-')
df['B'][replace1] = df['C']
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
replace = (df['B'] == '-') & (df['C'] != '-')
df.loc[replace, 'B'] = df['C']
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  0  5  -
1  1  b  b
2  2  c  c
3  3  8  -
4  4  9  e
```

I was curious if `np.where` is faster here and with sample data repeated `100000` times not:

*In real data is should be different, depends of length of DataFrame and number of matched values.*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, '-', '-', 8, 9],
                   'C': ['-', 'b', 'c', '-', 'e']})

#[500000 rows x 3 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [9]: %timeit df.loc[(df['B'] == '-') & (df['C'] != '-'), 'B'] = df['C']
60.7 ms ± 643 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit df['B']=np.where((df['B']=='-')&(df['C']!='-'),df['C'],df['B'])
66 ms ± 324 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I think reason is `np.where` processing all values, `loc` only filtered values. Also there are mixed strings with numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
import numpy as np 
df['B']=np.where((df['B']=='-')&(df['C']!='-'),df['C'],df['B'])
```

Dataframe looks like :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexing to update the values, like given below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, '-', '-', 8, 9],
                   'C': ['-', 'b', 'c', '-', 'e']})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['B'] == '-' and row['C']!='-'):
       df.loc[index,'B'] = df.loc[index,'C']
```

[image]